# Function returns wrong results. Finding last non-zero digit of n factorial

Tags: c++, numbers, codeblocks

I've tried to write a code that prints the last non-zero digit of n!(for non-negative integer n)
I thnik I've done everything correct. Can someone tell me why my code doesn't work? Everthing seems perfect up until i=15. What my code does it takes last non-zero digit and multiply it by n then it divides the result by 10 up until it has no 5 as a factor and finally prints last digit. Also what I wanted to achive is to print the correct result for very big n(like 10e15 or even bigger) but I think my code, even assuming it is correct won't be able to do this. Any hints will be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
int p(long long int n)
{
    if (n != 1) {
        long long int x = n * p(n - 1);

        while (x % 10 == 0)
            x /= 10;

        return x % 10;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: @FredLarson The goal is to avoid calculating the actual factorial by only handling the least significant digits. This avoids the overflow problems associated with factorials.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Interesting. I'd have to think about how that would work.

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with a debugger? It should let you spot where the results start deviating from your expectations.

Comment: Anything 5 factorial or greater will have `0` as the last digit.

Comment: @François Andrieux no I haven't, I don't even know how to use debugger.

Comment: `15 * p(14)` is `15 * 2` which is 30. Since the units is 0 the algorithm returns the next digit, 3. But this is incorrect, the next digit should be 8. This is due to truncating `!14` too much. I'm not sure how to determine the number of digits you need to keep. Probably as many digits as `n` has?

Comment: @somerndguy Using a debugger is a fundamental skill for developing in C++. I noticed you tagged Code::Blocks which is an IDE with its own debugger. I'm not familiar with it but it looks like you can read about it here : http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Debugging_with_Code::Blocks

Comment: @François Andrieux I've tagged codeblocks because from what I know c++ varies slightly depending on which IDE you chose, I thought it may be helpful, but I guess I shoudln't tag the question with codeblocks, should I remove the codeblocks tag then?

Comment: @somerndguy The IDE usually doesn't matter. Sometimes the compiler matters if the code contains unspecified behavior. Here it *might* matter if the size of your types matters but it probably doesn't.

Comment: If you don't "know how to use debugger", then this seems to be a much more important issue to look at, and it takes priority. Knowing how to effectively use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. This program sounds like an excellent opportunity to take advantage of, to learn how to use it so you can easily find and fix bugs in your own code, without needing anyone else's help.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik Yup, that's what i think, I'll try to play with debugger and see if i can resolve the problem, thanks to everyone.

Comment: Using `return x%100` should solve the correctness issue. The efficiency issue remains!

Comment: @Damien so obvious! I was trying to do smth like that within the loop, I've overlooked what was right under my nose. Thank you, do you have any sugestions how to solve the efficiency issue?

Comment: Sorry, this cannnot work. For example, if you multiply by 5^25 (4.710^14), you "create" 25 zeros...

Comment: You will find the math solution at se.math site ! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130352/last-non-zero-digit-of-a-factorial